# Remove const qualifier in Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: c++, templates, types, traits, visual-c++-6

The problem is a simple one, I want to remove the `const` qualifier from a type, using template metaprogramming. Usually you would use C++11 STL for that, or in older compilers do it yourself:

```
template <class Type>
struct StripConst {
    typedef Type Result;
};

template <class Type>
struct StripConst<const Type> {
    typedef Type Result;
};
```

However VC 6.0 is an old compiler and it does not support partial template specialization. It supports full specialization, which can sometimes be tricked into partial, like this:

```
template <class Type>
struct StripConst {
    template <class OtherType>
    struct VC6Helper {
        // ...
    };

    template <>
    struct VC6Helper<Type> {
        // ...
    };
};
```

But this seems pretty much useless at this point - no way to match to `const Type`.

I know that the answer is likely implemented in VC 6.0 version of Loki, but the link at its homepage is broken.

You may question the motivation to still use the aging VC 6.0 and you are probably right - but the binaries produced by it outperform what I get from Visual Studio 2008 by a factor of 2 and Visual Studio 2012 by 1.5. So, yeah, we still use it ...

Comment: Where do the performance numbers come from? Did you compare Debug builds?

Comment: Solution: remove "6.0" from "Visual C++ 6.0". There is no way that binaries produced by a compiler from some time in the past two decades are inherently twice as slow.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, they are twice as fast. That's right - VC 6.0 easily outperforms VS 2012. Sad but true. I guess it depends on application, this is some nonlinear numerical algebra.

Comment: @FredOverflow They are release builds, of course.

Comment: @theswine You look like an incredibly rude individual, right now. Keep it polite and professional.

Comment: @theswine it's not at all unusual for people posting similar questions to have made that mistake.

Comment: @theswine: You're on SO. Do you know how often people are benchmarking debug / unoptimised builds? It's, sadly, a perfectly valid question.

Comment: ... and face up to the idea that you're almost certainly misconfiguring something. I don't much fancy my chances of convincing you of this, though.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Well if I'm using VC6, doesn't it kind of mean that I have been doing it for a while? If I was a beginner, I would be using 2012. You can't even buy 6.0 anymore.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My aim was not to flame about which version gives faster builds, I was simply interested in a solution to a C++ (or subset thereof) problem.

Comment: Not really. It doesn't mean anything. It happens way too often and with all sorts of users. Asking that as the first thing only helps to avoid wasting time, unless the user takes it as personal insult and goes ballistic, but that's just sad.

Comment: It would be very rare for a compiler to get slower.  However it is common for run time libraries and extras to get more bloated, causing bigger, slower binaries.  Also, the newer RTLs have a lot of extra security/checking/etc. stuff, by default.  You might be able to switch some of that off. When you benchmarked VC2012 was it a proper, paid for, version?  The free "express" versions frequently have the optimisation crippled.

Comment: @MichaelJ Yes, that was professional version from MSDN AA. The buffer overrun checks were disabled, maximize speed enabled. Again, this is numerically dense code, there is not much time spent in the runtime. My guess is that the compiler got worse with introduction of the C# language. Note that g++ 4.6.something gives code that runs slightly faster than the VC6 code on the same hardware but in linux.

Comment: @theswine -- C# is a whole different compiler (though they probably share a bit of back-end).  MS do benchmark these things and a compiler change that made the binaries slower would likely sound alarm bells.  I'm betting on bloated runtimes.  Are you using MFC, ATL or anything like that?  Is the VC6 binary single or muli thread model?  Are the RT Libs dynamically linked (not statically)?  --- I am just speculating here.  You have probably thought of everything but there is no harm reviewing in case something slipped past you.  :-)

Comment: @MichaelJ Yes, I understand that C# is compiled by a different frontend, but still ... maybe it is also related to changes in the C++ language or introduction of x64. No MFC or ATL, just a simple console application doing a lot of computation. RT libs are multithreaded dynamic as far as I remember (is there any real difference in performance in static vs dynamic RT?).